# PHP array multidimensional: foreach starting from determinate level

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array that looks like the one below:

```
Array
(

[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [hotel_code] => 15ad7a
                [checkout] => 2018-04-26
                [checkin] => 2018-04-24
                [destination_code] => 1c6e0
                [products] => Array

                .... etc ....

            )
         [1] => Array
            (
                [hotel_code] => 193c6c
                [checkout] => 2018-04-26
                [checkin] => 2018-04-24
                [destination_code] => 1c6e0
                [products] => Array

                .... etc ....
            )
```

Wanting to create a simple pagination of the results, taking from the array 15 records at a time, through the following code I can recover the first 15 records.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data['results'] as $key=>$val){
$i++;
$selez_hotel_code = '' . $val['hotel_code'] . '';
if($i == 15) break;
}
```

Now, how can I get the next 15 values from the array?
I tried to start the foreach directly from record 15, setting it as follows

```
$i = 0;
foreach($data['results'][14]['hotel_code'] as $val){
$i++;
$selez_hotel_code = '' . $val . '';
if($i == 15) break;
}
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Its better to use `for loop` for this type of situation

Comment: Ok. But I do not know how to determine that the loop must start from level 14 of the array.

Comment: You have to send the start count number from the UI by which you will determine from where to start the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `for` loop, to specify the start and the end:

```
$start = 15 ;
$length = 15 ;
$max = count($data['results']);
for ($idx = $start; $idx < $start + $length && $idx < $max; $idx++) {
    $val = $data['results'][$idx]['hotel_code'] ;
    $selez_hotel_code = $val ;
}
```

Note that I've added a verification to avoid to loop over the maximum of results (`$idx < $max`).

Comment: Perfect! By changing the code according to my needs, it works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_GET` to paginate. Just have a `for` loop that uses this param if set, 0 if not. Something like this:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 0;
for ($i = $page; $i < ($page + 15); $i++) {
    // $data['results'][$i] . . .
}
```

And when clicking on "next page" or whatever you're using, set the `page` param